# Update an object with the scroll value as the page scrolls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

So I thought this would be easy but thinking about it, I can't figure out a way to pass the changing scroll value into an object?

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve https://www.fbf8.com/ notice when you scroll the polygonal objects are manipulated based on the scroll value. Yes I am assuming they are using three.js or maybe the plugin I am using [FSS.js](http://wagerfield.github.io/flat-surface-shader/) (might be custom) I'll inspect the source later but thats unrelated it's just an example.

Like I said I am using FSS.js and here is an instance of the `FSS.plane`

```
var geometry = new FSS.Plane(1600, 835, 6, 15);
```

I am trying to figure a way to pass into the constructor a changing value (scrollPos).

So I hope I am making sense now, here is a useless example but should provoke what my angle is.

```
var pos = 0;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    pos = $(document).scrollTop();
});

var geometry = new FSS.Plane(1600, 835, pos, 15);
```

Comment: I am going to drop this question and rethink another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the initiation function in your on scroll function

`$(document).scroll(function() {
        var pos = $(document).scrollTop();
        var geometry = new FSS.Plane(1600, 835, pos, 15);
    });`

Comment: Yeah this crossed my mind, but I thought this may cause performance issues, don't know why I should have at least tried it :)

Comment: Oh actually I remember doing this. Problem is `geometry` needs to be used outside the function. Last night I was thinking about wrapping all the code inside the function ill try that.

Comment: Maybe you could use a buffer and a threshold to see if it has scrolled more than just a few pixels, that could help I guess :)

And to use the geometry object outside, you can use it like this:
`var geometry;    
$(document).scroll(function() {
var pos = $(document).scrollTop();
geometry = new FSS.Plane(1600, 835, pos, 15);
});`

Comment: yeah I know that but the values inside geometry don't update as the page is being scrolled rendering it useless to even pass it into the function in the first place... Looking at f8 source code looks like they use http://zynga.github.io/scroller/demo/canvas.html I think I need to rethink another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code produced by Michael is right. The only thing that need to be done is updating the `geometry` when you scroll (instead of recreating the object like Ronnel said).

Look into your `FSS.Plane` object and search for an updatePosition method and call it after `pos = $(document).scrollTop();`

If this doesn't work, then maybe the scrollTop method always return the same thing. Depends on what you point with `document`